# the Process in the Tiers&Nodes doesn't display on the Application Dashboard

Tags: appdynamics

i found my process can be found under the Tiers&Nodes but i can not see it on  the Application Dashboard, how can i make it could be see on the Application Dashbard? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

"Tiers & Nodes" shows any Node which has registered with the Controller in the Application.

On the "Application Dashboard" you will see a flow map of all registered Business Transactions with entry points on the Nodes in the Application.

So I am guessing that you are seeing the Node, but don't have any registered Business Transactions (check the "Business Transactions" screen to confirm).

i.e. You can see the service but not any details of any code execution

You need to update your Business Transaction Detection rules / push traffic into the Application in order to register Business Transactions. These will be seen under "Business Transactions" once registered and visible on relevant Application / Tier / Node flow maps.

See the following documentation:

- Business Transactions - https://docs.appdynamics.com/appd/22.x/latest/en/application-monitoring/business-transactions
- Configure Business Transactions - https://docs.appdynamics.com/appd/22.x/latest/en/application-monitoring/business-transactions/configure-business-transactions
- Flow Maps Documentation - https://docs.appdynamics.com/appd/22.x/latest/en/application-monitoring/business-applications/flow-maps (see "Live Entity Data" for what is shown on flowmaps)